# Convert nested dictionary list to multi column dataframe

Tags: python

I have a nested dictionary list that looks like this.

```
{'a': [{'aa': '10', 'bb': '11'}, {'aa': '12', 'bb': '13'}], 'b': [{'aa': '14', 'bb': '15'}, {'aa': '16', 'bb': '17'}]}
```

and I would like to convert the dictionary list above to a multi column dataframe, preferably like this.

**The dictionary might not be the same length

```
a       b   
aa  bb  aa  bb
10  11  14  15
12  13  16  17
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your desired structure suggests that `('a', 'aa')`, `('a', 'bb')` are part of the same record as `('b', 'aa')` and `('b', 'bb')`, but that's not at all clear from the nested dictionary. Do you just assume that the lists will always contain matching dictionaries? (i.e. how should it be clear that `10`, `11`, `14` and `15` should be part of the same record?)

Comment: @Grismar yes, the dictionary key inside the list will always be the same, only the value is changed

Comment: @Grismar the reason i am looking for a multilevel column dataframe is that only the top level of the column is changed, while the 2nd level of the column is always the same

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to myself, but welcome any simpler way to do that.
Multilevel column dataframe requires tuple as a column name.

```
reform_dict = defaultdict(list)
        for a, data in dataset.items():
            for d in data:
                reform_dict[('a', 'aa')].append(d['aa'])
                reform_dict[('a', 'bb')].append(d['bb'])

df = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k, pd.Series(v)) for k, v in reform_dict.items()]))
```